# Remove navigation value fails

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have an object with a 1 to many relation:

```
  public class Setting
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public  virtual ICollection<Ovalue> Values { get; set; }
  }

  public class Ovalue
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public  string Value { get; set; }
  }
```

and a API methode

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UpdateSetting([FromBody]Setting setting)
{
  Context.Update(setting);
  Context.SaveChanges();

  return Ok(roleSetting);
}
```

I wrote tests where I add values to Settings and 1 test where I remove an existing one.

Add :

```
...
      Ovalue newValue = new Ovalue ()
      {
        Value = "1000"
      };

      Ovalue newValue2 = new Ovalue ()
      {
        Value = "2000"
      };

      Setting0.Values.Add(newValue);
      Setting0.Values.Add(newValue2);
...
```

Remove :

```
..
  Setting0.Values.Remove(Setting0.Values.First());
...
```

My add works fine, it creates a new row in my Ovalue table but when I remove it, it doesn't remove the row

Comment: You calling SaveChanges();after remove?

Comment: Context.SaveChanges(); as u see

Comment: ok i found a solution

Comment: Context.Entry(settingsOld).CurrentValues.SetValues(newsetting);